# VSTS Build with Windows 10 SDK for Fall Creators Update (10.0.16299.15)

Tags: uwp, azure-pipelines

We have created a uwp app with *Windows 10 SDK for Creators update (10.0.16299.15),*
and now we want to integrate that into the CI on VSTS. So updated the build agent with latest SDK.
But our we builds fails with not able to find types like below:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>   [D:\Windows-universal-samples-master\Windows-universal-samples-master\Samples\Logging\cs\Logging.csproj]"

we even tried to build the samples from SDK download page, with same result.

**Build Agent OS:** Windows 2012 R2 Server

Are we missing anything?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828656/xamlcompiler-error-wmc1006-cannot-resolve-assembly-or-windows-metadata-file-mi/46841808#46841808

Comment: deleting .vs,bin and obj folders didn't help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you build the project through MSBuild and Visual Studio on that build machine manually? Can you reproduce this issue with new project? Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: No, we are not able to build the project on MSBuild on build machine. Since the build machine is Windows 2012 R2, the project does not open in VS. We are able to repro the issue with samples from the SDK download page.

Comment: manual MSBuild output on the build machine - https://1drv.ms/t/s!AidPG11wBFc1roJpI8267fpuLUpqLQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **NuGet Restore task** to restore packages. There is **Universal Windows Platform** build template, so the simple way is that:

1. Click New to create build definition
2. Select Universal Windows Platform template=>Apply

Comment: Thanks for the help, we had the Nuget restore step, but it was not the latest version 4.3. After changing it to latest version 4.3, the build works. I could figure that out from the UWP build template.

Comment: @Naresh as far as I know the uwp build template uses a hosted vs 2017 which is limited to anniversary update sdk. above that the build fails for me. did you change any settings or did you, youself installed the latest sdks on the hostel vs 2017? if yes then how?